# flex bitmapData draw - how the set where to draw

Tags: apache-flex, draw, bitmapdata

i have a class thats create a class with bitmapData that merge 2 IBitmapDrawable.
one of them is 24*20 while the other is 16*16.
i want to draw the smaller first in a bitmapData object which its width and height are 24*20
but i want to draw it in the center of the big bounds.

does anyone know's how to do that? 
thanks...

```
if (baseIcon) {
    var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(baseIconWidth,baseIconHeigt,true, 0x00FFFFFF);
    result.draw(baseIcon,new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0));
    if (indicatorIcon) {
       result.draw(indicatorIcon,new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0));
    }
    bitmapData = result;
    baseIcon = null;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (baseIcon) {
    var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(baseIconWidth,baseIconHeigt,true, 0x00FFFFFF);
    var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
    m.translate(baseIconWidth/2 - baseIcon.width/2,baseIconHeight/2 - baseIcon.height/2);
    result.draw(baseIcon,m);
    if (indicatorIcon) {
       result.draw(indicatorIcon,new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0));
    }
    bitmapData = result;
    baseIcon = null;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at `matrix` parameter in BitmapData.draw, use translated matrix.